# Implementing copy of Android App DB file for backup/restore is this proper way?

Tags: android

I am using java methods to copy my application sqlite db from the application data directory to a folder in sd and have code to restore these file back to the application data directory. Is this a proper way of doing it? Are there potential errors or data corruption since it's a database file?

Comment: One issue I could see would be with uninstalling the app leaving behind database files.

Comment: The db files are in the app data directory so it will be uninstalled together. But I just see it as not a proper way to do it... What is Google guideline to do this?

Comment: ah ok good. I don't know of a guideline that exists in reference to this feature, but it should work fine as @caner describes.  I am doing something similar but I just grab the whole database as a string (not a humanness database) and save/restore that.

Answer (score 0):

It's perfectly fine to do so. SQLite files do not have any dependencies to other files, so copying them to SD card will achieve your goal. You can check the contents of SQLite files with [SQLite browser](http://sqlitebrowser.sourceforge.net/) if you want to make sure.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest exporting your DB to JSON format, and save that on an external location for backup/restore. That way, you can control the data you backup (maybe you want to skip backing up some confidential data?) and you can allow advanced restore features (restore only the data and not the preferences).

In order to do that, you need to represent every table with a class (if your using ORM - this is needed anyway), and then just use one of the JSON libraries, like "Gson", to get the JSON representation of the DB. After that, you can save it to some file wherever you'd like.